# Can not check radiobutton

Tags: java, android, radio-button

why I can not check the same radiobutton after I uncheck it programmatically, when I click next button, unless I check another radiobutton.

This is the code that unchecks radiobuttons:

```
        if(q.trim() != null || q.trim() != ""){
            questionView.setText(q);
            r1.setChecked(false);
            r2.setChecked(false);
            r3.setChecked(false);

            r1.clearFocus();
            r2.clearFocus();
            r3.clearFocus();

            r1.setText(varNames.get("ra0"));
            r2.setText(varNames.get("ra1"));
            r3.setText(varNames.get("ra2"));
        }
```

And this is where I try to check it:

```
public void questionClicked(View view) {

    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.firstQuestion:
            if(!checked) {
                r1.setChecked(true);
            }
            getAnswer(R.id.firstQuestion);

            break;
        case R.id.secondQuestion:
            if(!checked) {
                r2.setChecked(true);
            }
            getAnswer(R.id.secondQuestion);

            break;
        case R.id.thirdQuestion:
            if(!checked) {
                r3.setChecked(true);
            }
            getAnswer(R.id.thirdQuestion);

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you don't have to use .setChecked to any of these radio buttons, because bydefault when they are clicked they get checked/unchecked. Try to remove the lines that you .setCheck the radiobuttons.

Comment: Yes, I tried it but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make a method of clearing checked radio button. And call it everytime you click "next" button. Here is an example:

```
private void clearcheck(){        
        if(q.trim() != null || q.trim() != ""){
            questionView.setText(q);
            r1.setChecked(false);
            r2.setChecked(false);
            r3.setChecked(false);

            r1.clearFocus();
            r2.clearFocus();
            r3.clearFocus();

            r1.setText(varNames.get("ra0"));
            r2.setText(varNames.get("ra1"));
            r3.setText(varNames.get("ra2"));
        }
}
```

Call it like clearcheck(); in onclick of your next button.